# How to set BinaryType of SignalR

Tags: signalr

I make my signalrR connection in JavaScript like so:

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
  //do something         
});
```

In using WebSockets I can set the BinaryType property like so:

```
var wsUri = "ws://localhost:8080/whiteboard/websocket";
var websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
websocket.binaryType = "blob";
```

or

```
websocket.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
```

can i set this property for SignalR and if so how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can't, at least up to the latest officially released version (2.x). SignalR is a set of layered abstactions over a physical connection, where all those abstractions must work with different transport strategies (`WebSockets` being just one of them), therefore they must represent a common subset of features.

Anything related to the required type of data transmission/serialization is handled by SignalR automatically, except for certain portions when using a `PersistentConnection`, where only `string`s can be used. There is some space for changing some behaviors by injecting custom implementations, but I think this one would be very hard to do and probably conflicting with SignalR's general goals.

Comment: Hi, thanks I was beginning to think as much. Is there an alternative to SignalR that will support this?

Comment: Personally, not that I'm aware of (apart from raw WebSockets).